# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Runs Slow

Tags: 12.04, graphics, performance

I am new ubuntu user.

I am using ubuntu for web development.

For that i have installed XAMPP for Linux,Ubuntu and Chromium Browser.

But i dont know why it is too much slow.

Help is needed.

Thank you.

My system Configuration is :
Processor: Intel Pentium CPU G620 @ 2.60GHz x 2
RAM: 2GB
Available Disk Space: 103GB
Swap: 2GB

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by slow? What exactly is it that's slow? If it's general UI snappiness, it would be helpful to know what graphics card and driver you are using.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i check my graphics card?

Comment: Open up a terminal and run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`.

Comment: OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Desktop x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:

Answer (score 1):

The low free disk space is the culprit... I experienced it too and it definitely doesn't feel good. Try and free up some space by transferring stagnant data to other partitions or external hard drives.

As for your gpu, unless you spent extra bucks for a discrete gpu, you have got a sandybridge era cpu which comes with integrated intel HD graphics(HD 2000)!!

You can get OpenGL information about your gpu using command "glxinfo" without quotes.

OR, if your chromium browser can access OpenGL, enter about:gpu in URL bar of Chromium and hit enter!

Cheers and don't forget to mark this as your answer! :)

Comment: But i have 103 gb available and in file system i have 30 gb available i think there is no problem of free disk space.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry, i didn't see the gb, i thought it was mb;; wait, i'll figure this out...

Comment: Ok, I get it... The Frontend of ubuntu 12.04 LTS has Unity and your igpu is definitely slow as it definitely requires more power in the graphics department... 

If you have access to a graphic card, maybe one from your friend's, you can try it out to see if it speeds things up...

Comment: what do you mean by igpu??

Comment: By igpu, i mean integrated gpu which comes on-die with your processor... u see, the pentium g620 is a stripped down version of sandy-bridge core i3!

Comment: I think u got your answer... hd 2000 is slower than geforce 210 by the way... bye